# MYSQL замена конца строки при условии

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица:

```
id | data 
1  | 'text<br />'
2  | 'text'
3  | 'text'
4  | 'text<br />'
```

Возможно ли без использования PHP "обрезать" `<br />` в конце текста первой и четвёртой записи?

Мои знания позволяют только сделать выборку таких записей запросом - `SELECT id, data FROM table WHERE data LIKE '%<br />'`

Answer (score 0):

можно сделать только с помощью javascript, оно будет выглядит примерно таким образом:

```
var result =$(#tableId).children()[индекс дочернего элемента].innerHTML
```

и делать с этой переменной все что угодно

Comment: Я имел в виду заменить тэг <br /> непосредственно в базе данных, не на выводе

Comment: что делает тэг <br/> в бд?

Comment: или зачем вы <br/> вставляете в текст?

Comment: испульзуйте ругулярные выражения, потом заменяйте на пустую строку , это тоже через js

Comment: Не я автор движка на котором используется сайт, такая вот система. Просто нужно убрать <br /> из бд.

Comment: Если используете SQL в качеству СУБД, напишите триггер, который будет очищать от </br>.

Answer (score 0):

Вы сказали что вам нужно заменить конечный `<br />` тэг в бд, это вполне можно сделать одним запросом при помощи `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```
UPDATE table SET data = REGEXP_REPLACE(data,'\<br \/\>$', '') WHERE data LIKE '%<br />'
```

В итоге будет произведено удаление существующих `<br />` в конце текста из всех записей в поле `data`.